# Swagger base path with a kubernetes fan out path

Tags: kubernetes, swagger

**Set up**

I use kubernetes to send users to containers running stuff on certain ports.

For instance for something that I have running on a container in a pod on port `8080`, the user goes to `www.example.com/mt`, then `/mt` forwards them to the container running on `8080` which is my case is a container with an application that has a swagger spec.

**Question/Problem**

My swagger application at `www.example.com/mt/swagger-ui.html`
will send it's POST/GETs etc to `www.example.com:443/api/...` when it should be `www.example.com/mt/api/...`

Does anyone know how too even approach this problem. Is it in swagger or kubernetes?

**Potentially helpful notes:**

My .yaml file contains this that does the port forwarding

```
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /ui
        backend:
          serviceName: neo4j-service
          servicePort: 9205
      - path: /pg
        backend:
          serviceName: neo4j-service
          servicePort: 8181
      - path: /mt
        backend:
          serviceName: neo4j-service
          servicePort: 8080
```